# Read local text files js

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, with my chrome extension I need to read a text file. I'm trying to use this to just output the text file to the console

```
$.get('text.txt', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

But in console it outputs the data of the webpage, not my text file at all.

EDIT- Now I understant how jQuery.get works. I have my local text file and jQuery.get is meant for server files. I need a way to read local text files. Any help here?

Comment: Please share the data value printed on your console

Comment: I would, but it's too long. It's literally just the HTML of the webpage, nothing to do with my text file. Also it contains some private stuff

Comment: Accessing local files is not allowed by chrome because of security for our privacy.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the *dataType* (that you're expecting back from the server) as *text*:

```
$.get('text.txt', function(data){
  console.log(data);
}, 'text');
```

Comment: Just tried it, same result. To clarify, the text document isn't from the server, its just a document in the same folder as the script.

Comment: @WilliamFlinchbaugh, still `$.get()` is a server request:)

Comment: True you are right, but I still gotta get this to work

Comment: @WilliamFlinchbaugh, is there any error in console?

Comment: Nope no error. It literally just uses the HTML of the webpage instead of my text file. I don't really get it

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION:

**It will not load files from your local filesystem this way**

> You need to put it on a web server and load it from there. On the same site as you have the JavaScript loaded from.

Creating the webserver on **localhost** should work in Chrome, 
As it doesn't support reading files from the local filesystem by default.

> Additionally, you can start chrome using option --allow-file-access-from-files, which would allow access to local files.

Answer (score 0):

You can read local files like so:

```js
function readTextFile(file) {
  const fReader = new FileReader();
  fReader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  fReader.onloadend = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML = event.target.result;
  }
}

const input = document.getElementById('myfile');
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  readTextFile(input.files[0])
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
<div id="contents"></div>
```

[Documentation for the FileReader.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read files, in this exeple I use a csv file, but you can use txt to.

In my case, I use a input with type 'file' and with a onChange I load the file. By other part, I have a ref for indicate the source.

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" ref="doc_categories" onChange="read_file">
```

In the method 'read_file', I get the first file and I check that exist by his name.

```
this.file = this.$refs.doc_categories.files[0];   

if(this.file.name != undefined){
     const reader = new FileReader();
     if (this.file.name.includes(".csv")) {
        reader.onload = (res) => {
            this.content = res.target.result;
        };
        reader.onerror = (err) => console.log(err);
        reader.readAsText(this.file);
     } else {
       this.content = "check the console for file output";
       reader.onload = (res) => {
         console.log(res.target.result);
       };
       reader.onerror = (err) => console.log(err);
       reader.readAsText(this.file);
     }
}else{
  $.notify('Error to read the file.');
}
```

This code comes from vue code and I tried to migrate to js vanilla.
I hope it helped you.